# Change a View's instance variable via Model

Tags: java, model-view-controller

edit: look my answer for my real problem.

For the first time i'm trying to apply a MVC pattern.
In View.java I display waypoints on a map. I would like to change the waypoint's value. So I suppose to do it in the Model.java.

I've tried with a simple test to change an integer variable.

View.java:`

```
int x = 12;
public int getx(){
    return this.x;
}`
```

Model.java:

```
int a = View.getx();

public void setx(int n){
    n=n+2;
}
```

And in my main, I call view.java  then model.java : If I do print(x) in View, do the x will be updated ?

Anyway, **int a = View.getx(x)** doesn't work (static ref, non static method).

Thanks for your help, I hope it's understandable.

Comment: Why is the view not holding the model instance ? Also, where's the controllers?

Comment: Idk why, I've never did a MVC pattern. I don't need controllers for the moment.

Comment: The controller is what updates the model via a setter method,  which, in turn, should update the View.

Answer (score 0):

Can't comment on how you're applying the MVC pattern but your error is simple.

`public int getX()`

is an instance method of class `View`. You're accessing it like a class method (or a static method) by calling `View.getX()`. You need to instantiate a `View` class

```
View v = new View();
v.getX();
```

will work

EDIT:

> Idk why, I've never did a MVC pattern. I don't need controllers for the moment

The best way to learn MVC pattern in my opinion is to pick up an application development framework like Android, iOS, or Java Swing. These frameworks have their roots in MVC and make pretty clear distinctions between Models, Views, and Controllers when used correctly.

Answer (score 0):

In PHP MVC, the view listens to the model changes. Not the reciprocal.
Please see the following as a pseudo-code. I'm not so sure anymore about Java syntax. But I just try to show you a principle.

Define a model with an optional parameter (`waypoints`) in constructor, a property `waypoints`, a getter and a setter for handling the property `waypoints`:

```
class myModel {
    int waypoints = 12;

    public MyModel(int waypoints = 0){
        waypoints = waypoints;
    }

    public int getWaypoints(){
        return this.waypoints;
    }

    public void setWaypoints(int n){
        this.waypoints = this.waypoints + n;
    }
}
```

After that define a view which becomes a model instance as constructor parameter and has a function to display the waypoints from the model (!).

```
class myView {
    MyModel model;

    public MyView(MyModel model){
        model = model;
    }

    public void printWaypoints(){
        print(model.getWaypoints);
    }
}
```

Now testen:

```
// TEST 1:
// Init the model with a waypoints value.
MyModel model = new MyModel(182);
MyView view = new MyView(model);
view.printWaypoints(); // Displays 182.

// TEST 2:
// Init the model with no value.
MyModel model = new MyModel();
// Change waypoints value.
model.setWaypoints(43);
MyView view = new MyView(model);
view.printWaypoints(); // Displays 43.
```

Please notice, that the model has to be changed before instantiating the view.

I think, when you'd pass the model to the view "by reference", then it wouldn't matter, when you make the changes in the model.

Model class remains the same. But the view class' constructor changes:

```
class myView {
    MyModel model;

    // Notice the & (ampersand). You pass a reference to a model instance.
    public MyView(MyModel &model){
        model = model;
    }

    public void printWaypoints(){
        print(model.getWaypoints);
    }
}
```

Now again testen:

```
// TEST 3: NOT PERSONALLY TESTED
MyModel model = new MyModel();
MyView view = new MyView(model);
// Change waypoints value after view creation.
model.setWaypoints(193);
view.printWaypoints(); // Displays 193.
```

I hope this helped.